# Use variable inside Firebase snapshot function

Tags: swift, firebase

This question is not duplciated because others don't work and are not exactly like mine. I want to set the value of this snapshot in the `var` `averageMark`.
Like in this **code**:

```
func initAverageMark(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {

    let userRef = ref.child("users").child((user?.uid)!).child("mark")

    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
        if let mark: Double = snapshot.value as? Double {
            self.averageMark = mark
        }
        print("res: \(self.averageMark)") // 1st print
        completion(true)

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    print("res: \(self.averageMark)") // 2nd print
}
```

**My issue** is that the variable get a value inside the snapshot function but is nil outside of this function. The first print is "2.0" (which is correct) and the second is nil.

The real trouble is that I alreay did soemthing like that without any problem...

How is it possible? We can only use the values inside the snapshot? Thanks

Comment: I added completion to force the task performing sync.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642535/return-value-for-function-inside-a-block

Comment: Not working... That's why i ask it again.

Comment: is this func in a viewController or its own struct/class?

Comment: @Ro4ch This func is in its own class. I call it from a `viewController`

Comment: I had something similar. I needed access to an array so I created an array in my viewController that pointed to the array in the fetch function that was in the enclosure. So it was like this myVCArray = fetch.fetchArray.